# Reactstrap Progress not rendering

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to render a progress bar and a button using reactstrap@7.1.0. The button is rendered where as the progress bar is not rendered. What am i missing?
Also bootstrap version is 4.2.1.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Progress,Button } from 'reactstrap';

const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
    <Button color="danger">Danger!</Button>
    <div className="text-center">25%</div>
    <Progress value="25" />
    here i am 


  </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The following HTML code is rendered

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the component showing up in the React tab of your console or in your DOM tree ?

Comment: @Treycos yes. It shows in the react tab

Comment: When using the element inspector on your generated HTML, are there any CSS rules hiding your component or setting its width/length to 0 ?

Comment: @Treycos No. Does it have anything to do with propTypes? Since it is written in the documentation.

Comment: Is you console printing out a warning saying that the propTypes failed for your component ?

Comment: @Treycos  No warnings on console. propTypes was just my wild guess.

Comment: Got it solved. Missed out on importing bootstrap in index file.

Comment: Oh, alright, you can post it as an answer and accept it if you think it could help other people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missed out on importing bootstrap in index file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```