# Progress bar with react-bootstrap is not showing up

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to add a Progress bar used as a review, it's really strange because nothing is displayed.

I try to just copy/paste examples from react-bootstrap and it's not working at all. I try also the material-ui one but the same things...

[image]

I do not understand why, I am not using it as a weird way.

```
<Col>
                        <Row className="review-summary">
                            <p> 5 </p>
                            <ProgressBar variant="info" now={60} bsPrefix="review-summary-progress"/>
                        </Row>
                        <Row className="review-summary">
                            <p> 4 </p>
                            <ProgressBar variant="info" now={60} bsPrefix="review-summary-progress"/>
                        </Row>
                        <Row className="review-summary">
                            <p> 3 </p>
                            <ProgressBar variant="info" now={60} bsPrefix="review-summary-progress"/>
                        </Row>
                        <Row className="review-summary">
                            <p> 2 </p>
                            <ProgressBar variant="info" now={60} bsPrefix="review-summary-progress"/>
                        </Row>
                        <Row className="review-summary">
                            <p> 1 </p>
                            <ProgressBar variant="info" now={60} bsPrefix="review-summary-progress"/>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
```

The css is :

```
.review-summary {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.review-summary p {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ff7255;
}

.review-summary-progress {
    color: #ff7255;
}
```

Any idea why nothing is displayed? I tried as well to move the progress bar elsewhere but same things...

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: import ProgressBar from 'react-bootstrap/ProgressBar'   please check the link https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/

Comment: here is why it is not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54618081/reactstrap-progress-not-rendering

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was the missing import in my component.
Try adding this in your imports:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: I would suggest adding it to index.js

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and placing the progress bar component inside of a column is what fixed it for me.

So it doesn't work like this:

```
<Row>
    <ProgressBar />
</Row>
```

But it works like this:

```
<Row>
   <Col>
       <ProgressBar />
   </Col>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your dependency. Either using `npm` or `yarn`.

```
npm update react-bootstrap@latest --save-dev
```

Another way to debug is set your `now` value which is a number that displays current progress of bar so ex. `now={50}`:

```
<ProgressBar striped variant="success" now={50} active="true" label=`${uploadPercentage}%`} value={`${uploadPercentage}`}/>
```

[More details.](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/)

Answer (score 0):

this resolved it for me,

make sure you have bootstrap CDN in place,
make sure numbers and in-line styling are accompanied by {} and {{}},
make sure the "" is on the key only and not on the value of in-line style

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
<span className="progress">
<span className="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={60} aria-valuemin={0} aria-valuemax={100} style={{width:"50%"}}>
</span>
</span>
```